# Swift Displaying All Users Except for Current User Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a tableview that populates with all of the Parse users in my database. I am trying to display all of the users except for the currently logged in user. My current solution is to only add objects to my array if they satisfy this condition

`if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username`

Unfortunately, this creates an issue as nothing is populated in my table.

Here is my full function:

```
 var userArray : NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        loadParseData()



    }
 func loadParseData() {

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                    for object in objects {

                        if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username {

                        self.userArray.addObject(object)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look into the subclass PFQueryTableViewController -> https://parse.com/docs.

There is an example in there of how to use this subclass, inside is a method for returning a query to the tableviewcontroller.

You will then find it easier performing this task using a queries again in the docs but it would look something like this.

```
var query = PFUser.query
query.wherekey(username, notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser.username)
return query
```

Comment: I think you mean `query.wherekey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser.username)` which would be the correct format, but I get an error `Extra argument 'notEqualTo' in call`

Comment: Sorry I added extra braces. Thanks!